# Box shadow color based on colors from image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to have the `box-shadow` adjust its color value, based on the colors in the image it's being applied to?

If you look at [abduzeedo's site](http://abduzeedo.com/tags/daily-inspiration), you will notice that the images all have unique `box-shadow` colors, often related to their parent image (pictured below).

[image]

I did notice that the CSS is being inserted in-line into the HTML, which says to me this is done through scripting, but how? Are these colors actually being pulled from their images or are they arbitrarily/manually generated?

I've tried searching for this on Google, but I'm not having much luck.  I'm not asking for a tutorial, mostly just what this is called, how to find it, or if it's even possible to do it dynamically, rather than randomly or manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332573/getting-the-most-frequently-appearing-color-of-an-image

Comment: I googled and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript

Comment: They are using [Vibrant.js](http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript for this as you mention.
There are a few different options of plug-ins that you can use but the two most populare are:

1. [Color Thief](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/)
2. [VibrantJS](http://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/)

Extract the dominant color of the image, and apply an inline `box-shadow` style with that color on the particular element.

Comment: I don't know why I never thought to google how to extract the color first...rookie mistake.  I was googling things like "box-shadow based on image color" and found nothing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Simplest approach would be to duplicate an image over other (using `position: absolute;`), like two layers, one over another, and then apply `filter: blur(16px);` on background image.

Checkout: [Codepen-demo](https://codepen.io/yogesh-hackx/full/bGEmRWv)

Comment: That's actually the most useful answer